# Can i create linq entities for List in Moss 2007?

Tags: 2007, list, wss-3.0

i did try using below syntax

[image]

but i got response like that

[image]

is that possible linq entities for sharepoint list in Moss 2007? or I'm going Wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use linq to shp 2010 but you can use this tool:http://linqtosharepoint.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Ovidiu..i follow your link and i installed it perfectly.but when open wizard and connect to sharepoint site than unable to connect sharepoint site.i wrote write url as well as credentails.have u any idea of this?